# Android TextUtils.isDigitsOnly returns true for empty string

Tags: android

```
android.text.TextUtils.isDigitsOnly("")
```

I'm using above code to check input string is a valid number or not but `isDigitOnly()` function return `true` for empty string.

How to make it to return `false` for empty string or there is other Android build in function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin) mentioned correctly this is actually a bug that persists until today. See [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36939578).

You can get around that by doing this:

**Java**

```
boolean myIsDigitsOnly(String str) {
    return !str.isEmpty() && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(str); 
}
```

Now you call your own custom method:

```
myIsDigitsOnly(""); // returns false
```

**Kotlin**

In Kotlin, you don't need `TextUtils` at all. Just create your own extension function like this:

```
fun String.isDigitsOnly() = all(Char::isDigit) && isNotEmpty()
```

[Try it out here!](https://pl.kotl.in/2uXYC5Td-)

---

<sub>Thanks to [silwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557157/silwar) who inspired me to make the Java one more concise.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for pointing to the location of the existing bug report. That bug was  created in Jan 2012. Wow.

Comment: I am confused... The Java Code is wrong, it still returns true if the string is empty. isn't it supposed to be "return !str.isEmpty() && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(str);" ?

Comment: @Pecana True, corrected! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin Users

Although its an old question with accepted answer, this is suggestion to improve this answer in **Kotlin language** by following code

```
fun String.myIsDigitsOnly(): Boolean {
   return TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(this) && this.isNotEmpty()
}
```

Now you can call your method like

```
"".myIsDigitsOnly() // returns false
```

or

```
"123523423".myIsDigitsOnly() // returns false
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add Kotlin code here. I also did, but using a different approach. +1